# regex wildcard and multiple files (used in grr)

Tags: python, regex

trying to get a regex format for grr(grr rapid response) for any files with content matching strings starting with sw, ending with sh, and any characters in between and of any length.
example. regex for swoosh, swou sh, swoo! $sh

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
/^sw.*sh$/
```

Where:

`^` mark the start

`.` mark any characters

`*` the expression before it can appear 0 or many times

`$` mark the end

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
sw.*?sh
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1sfMabb7-txhWUqS)

you can also take out the `?` non-greedy token like `sw.*?sh` but that will match the whole string "swoosh swish" as one match rather than 2